# When I change myfile to an nonexistent file I would like it to print one instead of the error

Tags: python

```py
try:    
     myfile = '/Urs/example/Documts/CompSci101Assignment3.odt'
except FileNotFoundError:    
     print("1")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/example/Documents/Assignment 3.py", line 56, in <module>
    createDictionaries()
  File "/Users/example/Documents/Assignment 3.py", line 21, in createDictionaries
    with open(myfile, 'r') as textfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Urs/example/Documents/CompSci101Assignment3.odt'
```

This is the error that occurs intead of printing "1"

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  What do you mean by "scramble"?  Also, could you edit the post and show the error you are getting?

Comment: `myfile = '/Urs/example/Documts/CompSci101Assignment3.odt'` assigns the string containing the path to `myfile`. It doesn't open the file or check if the file exists, so if the path is not valid you're not going to get any exceptions there. You need to put the part that actually opens the file inside the try block.

Comment: yeah sure, I mean when I enter a file that isn't actually a file so I get a fileNotFoundError!

Comment: The problem is the same: no matter how you get the candidate name for the file, the only way you can find out whether there's actually a file with that name is to *execute code that looks for the file* (for example, by trying to open it). Notice that the traceback for the exception shows the error happening *somewhere else in your code*, specifically, at the point where you make the `open` call, which is *outside* your `try` block.

Comment: so that is not the path to the file, doesnt look like its correct either, looks like there is a spelling mistake

Comment: Your code sample does not generate that error.   Please execute code samples before submitting to verify they display the same behavior you are seeking help for.

Answer (score 0):

```
#to open the file
try:
    myfile = open("/path/to/file.txt")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("1")

#to read each line
for line in myfile.readlines():
    print(line)
```

you might need a library that supports the open document format in order to read an .odt file like you have specified.